# Count amount of members in a class

Tags: java

I'm making a small game in java for school purposes.
Now I want to count the number of players, code I have:

```
    Player player1;
    player1 = new Player();

    player1.name = "Name1";
    player1.score = 0;
    player1.lives = 100.0;

    Player player2;
    player2 = new Player();

    player2.name = "Name2";
    player2.score = 0;
    player2.lives = 50.0;
```

Comment: You have to keep track of all the `Player` Objects by putting them in a `Collection` such as a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: Counting the number of instances of a class is tough, because it's hard to know when they go away. Easier might be to have a 'game' that counts the number of players in it.

Answer (score 1):

In the players use a [static variable](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/) count that increments in the player constructor.

```
private static int playerCount = 0;

//constructor
Player(){   
  playerCount++; 
}
```

Comment: What when the Object is destroyed?

Comment: I don't think for this application he cares.  He is just trying to keep a quick and dirty count.

Comment: If the object is destroyed you will have to implement your own garbage collector that recognizes if the collected object is of type Player and decreases the count by one.

Comment: I understand the implications of not accounting for the object being destroyed.  I just don't think it matters for his application.

Comment: @Grammin You might think it doesn't matter, but you're just guessing if it matters to him.  Either way, if it does become an issue, you've just embedded a bit of messy code that will require a bit of coare to properly cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the players in a list:

```
List<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
Player player;

player = new Player();
player.name = "Name1";
player.score = 0;
player.lives = 100.0;

allPlayers.add(player);

player = new Player();
player.name = "Name2";
player.score = 0;
player.lives = 50.0;
allPlayers.add(player);

allPlayers.size(); //Number of players
player = allPlayers.get(0); //Player 1
player = allPlayers.get(1); //Player 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about it is to use a container class, something that's a descendent of `java.util.Collections`.

When a player is added, he is added to the collection.  When the player drops out of the game, he is removed from the collection.  As a result, to determine the number of players at any moment in time, one only need to count the members of the collection (which is already implemented if you use a java.util pre-implemented Collection).

Even then, there are two techniques.  One of these are flawed, and I'll demonstrate the flawed technique first (which is not much better than the static counter example others have provided).

```
private static HashSet<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();

public Player() {
  players.add(this);
}

public static int getPlayerCount() {
  return players.size();
}
```

This leads to an interesting problem.  The Player count will never go down, as even if `Player` classes are dereferenced, the counting collection holds a reference preventing garbage collection.  This leads to the java version of a "garbage leak", but don't confuse it with the C/C++ "garbage leak" which is more nefarious.

The second technique arises from fixing the problems in the first.  Basically, it doesn't rely upon construction to register, as destruction is an unsafe means of deregistering.  Within a snippet of code you would have

```
HashSet<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
Player player = new Player("bob");
players.add(player);

... later on ...

players.remove(player);
```

or something equivalent.  Basically the main idea is to have your current player list at the same level as the player creation.  There are a million variants, depending on where the originating call comes from; however, the main idea is the same: explicit deregistering of the player, not directly tied to object life cycle.